# balloon popup extender inside gridview header displays on every postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, balloon-tip

I am new to balloon popup extender. I am giving a balloon popup extender for Gridview header,
This is my code. I don't know where I am going wrong. When I click a button on the page, the balloon popup extender appears on top left of the page, and it appears on every postback caused by any buttons on the page. I don't know to hide it and document.getElementById("blnHeaderRowA") gives null reference. Is there any workarounds?
<asp:BoundField HeaderText=""  DataField="Row_id"/>

```
   <asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate >
    
        <asp:Label ID="lblHeaderRowA" runat="server" Text="A" onmouseout="omo(this.BalloonPopupControlBehavior);"></asp:Label>
        <asp:BalloonPopupExtender Enabled="false" ID="blnHeaderRowA" runat="server" TargetControlID="lblHeaderRowA" UseShadow="true" DisplayOnMouseOver="true" Position="BottomRight" BalloonPopupControlID="pnlHeaderRowPopupA" DisplayOnClick="false" DisplayOnFocus="false"></asp:BalloonPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlHeaderRowPopupA" runat="server" ><asp:Label ID="lblHeaderRowPopupA" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" ></asp:Label></asp:Panel>
        
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblA" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("A") %>' ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

this is my javascript to hide the balloon popup extender

```
function omo(obj) {
        if (obj != null) {
            
            obj.hidePopup();
            
        }
    }
```

My main motto being, how to avoid BalloonPopupExtender from appearing on every postback of the page pertaining my code.
thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I have created a work around, call showPopup() and hidePopup() one after the other on each postback, and it disappears on each postback :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi add this to Page_Load outside !IsPostBack

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "hidePopup","document.getElementById('"+((Label)GvR045F.HeaderRow.FindControl("lblHeaderRowPopupA")).ClientID+"').BalloonPopupControlBehavior.showPopup();document.getElementById('"+((Label)GvR045F.HeaderRow.FindControl("lblHeaderRowPopupA")).ClientID+"').BalloonPopupControlBehavior.hidePopup();",true);
```

Thanks